# Jenkins job is waiting for next available executor

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins job is a Matrix build that should run on build machines labeled AAA and BBB. 
I have three build machines set up, each having label AAA and BBB. 
However, when I start the build job, the job does not execute. Instead, it goes to "pending - Waiting for next available executor" state. Why does not my job execute?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check the slave node configuration. 
"Usage" field should be "Utilize this slave as much as possible" instead of "Leave this machine for tied jobs only".

Comment: Also make sure #no of executers > 0 (openshift it defalts to zero)

Comment: I have a similar issue to OP, except that some nodes are failing to service jobs with matching labels and I already had the config options you suggested set. Any other suggestions on what to look at?

Answer (score 15):

Go to **Manage Jenkins -> Configure System** and increase the **number of executor** from 0 to 1

Comment: I found there that _"Jenkins took some agents offline because their key health metrics went below a threshold. If you don’t want Jenkins to do this, change the setting"_.   So it helps me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Nodes > Configure > ## of executors. Increase the number here.

Comment: That won't work with Kubernetes plugin. If you change the value from 0 to another one, then Jenkins will try to use master instead of slaves.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Elastic Axis](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Elastic+Axis) plugin. 
Afer installing it, in the multi configuration job you can find new axis added as Elastic axis. You just need to provide the label of the node. The job is built on all the nodes with that label. There is a check box provided to skip the nodes that are offline.

Answer (score 0):

For me, already 2 jobs were in progress when I tried to execute the third one and hence I got this "Jenkins job is waiting for next available executor" on executing 3rd job.
The first two jobs were automatically triggered (as per my scripts) hence, I didn't realise they were running. After aborting these two jobs to run the third one, this error got resolved.

So, if you face this issue, just check once if any other job is already running. If yes, aborting that job or running after that job is completed may help resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Jenkins ,deleted all .jenkins files.Then I reinstalled jenkins, created job and build it successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).